# Why do I sometimes need to prefix proc with & when passing it as an arg?

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm learning Ruby and have been told that, to quote Codecademy:

> When passing a proc to a method, an & is used to convert the proc into a block.

Hence the following works:

```
cube = Proc.new do |num| num ** 3 end
puts [1, 2, 3].map!(&cube) #errors without &
```

But if I pass a proc to a user-defined function, it works only *without* the `&` and errors *with* it.

```
foo = Proc.new do puts 'foo' end
def bar(cb)
  cb.call
end
bar(foo) #bar(&foo) results in error
```

So how should I understand the whole with-`&` and without-`&` difference? Is it to do with inbuilt methods (`map()`, in my case) vs. user-defined methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I pass a proc to a user-defined function, it works only without the & and errors with it.

That's because in your example `cb` is a positional argument. To declared it as a [block argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument), you need to prefix it with `&`:

```
def bar(&cb)
  cb.call
end

foo = Proc.new { puts 'foo' }
bar(&foo)
```

Or simply:

```
def bar
  yield
end

foo = Proc.new { puts 'foo' }
bar(&foo)
```

Having an actual block argument also allows you to skip the proc creation and call it as:

```
bar { puts 'foo' }

# or

bar do
  puts 'foo'
end
```

> So how should I understand the whole with-`&` and without-`&` difference?

There are 3 kinds of method arguments in Ruby:

- positional arguments, e.g. `foo(1, 2, 3)`
- keyword arguments, e.g. `foo(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)`
- block arguments, e.g. `foo { puts "hello" }`

Since procs are objects, you can pass them as positional or keyword arguments, just like any other object.

But if you want a proc to become a block argument, you need `&` to convert it.

Comment: So the reason I need the `&` in `map(&cube)` is because the internal method `map()` expects a block, not positional, argument, right?

Comment: @Mitya yes, exactly. As said in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#map-method): _"Calls the **block**, if given, with each element ..."_

Comment: @Mitya two real-life examples of methods that take a proc as a positional argument are [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#find-method) (in addition to a block) and [`Hash#default_proc=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Hash.html#default_proc-3D-method). But it's rather unusual.

Comment: Interesting. So just out of curiorisity, why do some inbuilt methods expect block arguments (`array.map`) and some proc (as positional) arguments, like those you mention?

Comment: @Mitya: *Every* method in Ruby automatically has exactly one optional block parameter. No more. No less. So, if you want to take two "functions" as arguments, one of them cannot be a block. Likewise, you can't use a block in an assignment because you can only assign objects and blocks aren't objects.